# wordpress adjust content to admin-bar height (thin and thicker admin bars)

Tags: html, css, wordpress

i am trying to develop my first wordpress theme. i have a fixed side bar with a logo icon and a menu button (and will also maybe have social media icons).

When user are not logged in to wordpress there is no admin-bar on top of the screen, so i am styling the side bar like this:

```
#masthead{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 40px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 999;
}
```

when a user is logged in there is a admin-bar on top of the screen. When the admin-bar is present the body tag has an addicional class: admin-bar, so i am changing my side bar like this:

```
.admin-bar #masthead{
    top: 32px;
}
```

the problem is that when i resize the window, it gets to a size where the admin-bar becomes thicker (46px). is there a way to "see" this difference with css?
I guess i could do it with media-queries, but if it would work with something like the solution for the thinner bar i think i would be happier.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: you can use developer tool (press F12), it is better if you create a demo

Comment: sorry, i don't understand what you mean...  =/

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do a handful of media queries to adjust the size of your CSS based on the admin bar.

For example:

```
@media all and (max-width: 699px) {
.admin-bar #masthead{ top: 46px; }
}
```

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/